# Algorithm for activation key- Security

Tags: algorithm, copy-protection

I'm writing a software application that the user needs to buy a license for and activate it. I need suggestions on how to start about writing a powerful algorithm for code generation and of course, code checking. I know that people can reverse engineer the code and make a keygen, however, my question is two parts:

1. In general, regardless of the application being cracked this way, how can I start writing an algorithm to accept a certain Serial or String or a combination. (e.g is that the right thing? e.g: the first number is from 3-9 the second should be the first - 3, while the third number should be the second * + ....whatever...??)
2. What is the best approach for protecting a Desktop application from piracy without dealing with the internet. Is it the algorithm (make it harder to reverse engineer), protect the source code from being seen after application is installed somewhere?? ...??

PS: Maybe it is worth to mention that I am using Java as my development language.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It sounds like you might benefit from the [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) approach.
2. This can be broken down into two sub points:

   - A. Have you read [this thread here on SO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473143/methods-to-stop-software-piracy) It might give you some breadth on the issue.
   - B. As @Jaka said, it's not a great challenge (from what I've read) to produce human readable code from Java byte code. You can run your code through [an obfuscator](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+obfuscator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to make it more difficult for someone to produce human readable code from it, but if someone really wants to read your code, they'll almost always find a way. The best approach to combat this is to take the advice in the SO thread I linked to: make it easier for someone to buy your app than for someone to steal it.

(edited after stated he's using Java)

Comment: It's compiled. JAVA Desktop application.

Comment: The problem with public-key crypto for serial number generation is that it creates incredibly long codes that are difficult for user's to enter. A 1024-bit key would generate code roughly 200 characters in length if base32 encoded. That doesn't even account for human perception issues like mistaking 1 (one) and l (lowercase L).

Comment: the link 'this thread here on SO?' leads to error page. i.e., page not found. please help

Answer (score 1):

For the license keys you could use an encryption with public-private keys. In this way you could either embed the private key into the software and encrypt a string which would mean something to your software (like which features of your software are licensed). Or you could embed the public and give the software a string with special meaning and sign it with your private key. The software could then check if the signature is valid.

**edit:** labratmatt was faster with the public-private key answer :)

Obviously second part of your protection would need to deal with making your software hard to disassemble and debug (this is how crackers examine your software and try to bypass the protection with a patch or they try to figure out how they can make a keygen). This part is actually much harder and involves techniques like encryption the whole executable and wrap it inside a loader which decrypts it at runtime. The loader can also use various techniques to detect the presence of debuggers.

**edit:** Since you mentioned that the application is written in JAVA, then this encrypting and packing step is even more important as JAVA can easily be decompiled into a very human readable form. There are "obfuscator" programs which mess around with the classes so that the decompilers can't generate readable code, but cracking this is still much easier than cracking something compiled to machine code.

If you don't want to spend time with developing your own protection you can also use one of commercial protection software. There are quite a lot of them to choose from and they offer numerous protection schemes (dongles, time based licenses,...)

Lots of commercial software uses packages like FlexNet, HASP, Wibu-key

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: encrypt the part of the application that provides licensed-only functionality.  The user needs a key you provide on purchase in order to use that portion of the code.

If you ever let the user run the code you want to protect before they've purchased, there is no significantly secure offline solution.  At best, you can stop the most casual piracy.

Answer (score 0):

You should also thing about doing it in a way that one key cannot be used on two different computers. Just to prevent a company buying one key and using it for many instalations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your own JRE too? Building a secure, capable activation system that deals smoothly with the range of user scenarios you'll encounter (people with no network connection, a firewall, a proxy server etc) and has been thoroughly tested in the field takes considerable domain expertise and time.

As a supplier of such systems we do have as self-interest to declare, but we also have data - we see many companies who put their trust in a developer who says they can put together a licensing system, then later they come back to us as it never did what they needed. This article (of mine) expands on the issues: http://knol.google.com/k/dominic-haigh/issues-to-consider-before-building-your/2zijsseqiutxo/6#

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-to-explain-drm-cannot-work/14254#14254

Even if you did put a very powerful lock on your software, pirates would still find a way to crack it and put it on a torrent site. (case in point: Spore)

You are talking about DRM, and there's no easy way (if any) to lock pirates out of pirating your software. And besides, you are competing with free products that can do what your software does (always the case), so you should focus more on making your software easy to install and use, not hard to install and use for more than you intended.